# Is there way to remove Thread Sleep code?

Tags: c#, event-log

With below code snippet, I am trying to do "Subscription to Windows Event Log".

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        EventLogWatcher watcher = null;
        try
        {
            EventLogQuery subscriptionQuery = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, "*[System/EventID=101]");

            watcher = new EventLogWatcher(subscriptionQuery);

            watcher.EventRecordWritten += new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(EventLogEventRead);

            // Activate the subscription
            watcher.Enabled = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                // Wait for events to occur. 
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
        catch (EventLogReadingException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening to events
            watcher.Enabled = false;

            if (watcher != null)
            {
                watcher.Dispose();
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void EventLogEventRead(object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
    {
        // Make sure there was no error reading the event.
        if (arg.EventRecord != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg.EventRecord.TimeCreated);
            Console.WriteLine(arg.EventRecord.FormatDescription());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The event instance was null.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Everything looks good over here, but is there any way that we can remove below thread sleep code?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                // Wait for events to occur. 
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
```

What could be other solution to that can invoke event happening?

Comment: Yes: click with your mouse at "for" so as to place the cursor on it, and then press and hold the "delete" key down until the problematic code snippet has been deleted.  In order to receive an answer, you are going to need to explain what you need to accomplish, and why the code you are showing does not accomplish it.

Comment: do you want waiting for stop request from user?

Comment: Are you wanting to wait 50 seconds before continuing? Or for a certain number of events to fire?

Comment: I want to keep reading the event logs till my exe is running

Comment: Did you consider writing it as a service if it needs to be run continuosly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway console will end, so you may want run until user says stop.

So, replace the lines of sleeping codes:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // Wait for events to occur. 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
```

With :

```
Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
do 
{
    cki = Console.ReadKey();
    // nothing to do and ready to recieve next pressed key.
} while (true);
```

Comment: a trick! JUST you don't check `cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape` !
if true let m,e know and edit my answer :)

Comment: then what should be in while

Comment: funny! just 'true' :)

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN, you can use waitone method of autoresetevent object.
For example:
[WaitOne example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten(v=vs.110).aspx)